# js Function queue

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, canvas, webgl

So essentially what I'm trying to do is have a queue of functions that I can add to. These functions are suppose to be drawing things to a canvas like in an requestAnimationFrame.

What I've tried:

```
var drawQueue = [];
function animate() {
    while (drawQueue.length !== 0) {
        drawQueue.shift()();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        animate();
    });
}
```

With that I was trying to add things like:

```
drawQueue.push(drawthing(0,0,0,0));
```

this would just run the function and push undefined to the array, this does how work if you just do this:

```
drawQueue.push(function () {
    console.log("derp");
});
```

or

```
drawQueue.push(functionName); //with no args
```

The but problem here is that I need to pass arguments to most of the functions I'm calling.

my Second attempt:

```
var drawQueue = [];
function animate() {
    while (drawQueue.length !== 0) {
        var data = drawQueue.shift();
        Object.apply(data.func, data.args);
    }   
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        animate();
    }); 
}
```

while adding function to the queue like:

```
drawQueue.push({func: functionName, args: [0,0,0,0]});
```

but I couldn't get that to work either, not 100% how to use Object.apply() and what exactly its doing...

So my question is how do I go about making my function queue or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add something to the queue like this:

```
drawQueue.push(drawthing(0,0,0,0));
```

All that is doing is calling `drawthing(0,0,0,0)` immediately and pushing the return result from executing the function into the queue.

---

Instead, you need to push an actual function into the queue like this:

```
drawQueue.push(function() {drawthing(0,0,0,0)});
```

---

If you want to just push the function and arguments into the queue separately like this:

```
drawQueue.push({func: functionName, args: [0,0,0,0]});
```

Then, you can pull an item off the queue and execute it like this:

```
var item = drawQueue.shift();
item.func.apply(this, item.args);
```

When you call `function.apply(a, b)`, it sets the `this` ptr to the first argument `a` and then calls the function with whatever arguments are in the `b` array.

Comment: If you're going to store the function and arguments, you may as well store the context.

Comment: @JuanMendes - that's up to the OP for whether the context needs to be something other than the global object or not.  They did not seem to need that in their original example, but obviously that would be a more general solution.

Comment: Probably why I prefer the first solution, let the caller decide what to bind in terms of arguments and context

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I needed to do the same! Have a look here: https://github.com/alexandernst/jniftilities#functions-queue

It's a small library that will do exactly what you're looking for. Please see the comments/examples in that same link.

Comment: Please don't just post a link, you should at least summarize it

Answer (score 0):

`while (drawQueue.length !== 0) {
  var data = drawQueue.shift();
  data.func(data.args);
}`

And use an `Object` for the arguments.